# Find greatest value of $y(x) = (0.9^x)(300x + 650)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

### Question and attempt

$y(x) = (0.9^x)(300x + 650)$

> Estimate at what x value that y reaches its maximum value

The only way I could think of would be to use derivatives, so I tried it:

$y'(x) = (0.9^x)' \times (300x + 650) + 0.9^x \times (300x + 650)'$
          $=$ [$\ln(0.9) \times 0.9^x \times 1$] $\times  (300x + 650) + 0.9^x \times 300$

So then I subbed in 0 to find where the turning point is:

$y(0) =\ln0.9 \times 0.9^0 \times (300(0) + 650) + 0.9^0 \times 300$
        $=\ln0.9 \times 650 + 300$
        ~ $231.51$

The problem is that $231.51$ is not the correct answer.

---

### The real answer

This is a table of values of the answer (see that it increases up to in between x = 7 and 8, then decreases):

```
x = 5: 1269.5535
x = 6: 1302.03045
x = 7: 1315.316475
x = 8: 1312.9249905
x = 9: 1297.85863815
```

Here is what the graph actually looks like (which tells me there is a turning point):

[image]

And here is the picture of the vertex:

[image]

So the x value at which the y value is at its maximum value is $7.3$

I'd like to know where I went wrong with the derivative idea, but I still would encourage answers describing any other way to solve the problem.

Comment: $y(0)$ doesn't have anything to do with the maximum; $y'(x) = 0$ does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your mistake was in evaluating $y'(0)$ as a means to find critical points.

To use the derivative, you don't evaluate $y'$ at $0$; you determine for what value(s) of $x$ solve $y'(x) = 0$.

So work on solving $$y'(x) =  [\ln(0.9) \times 0.9^x] \times  (300x + 650) + 0.9^x \times 300 = 0$$

Comment: Oops. Thanks. I'll retry.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: I don't think I can work out the algebra. Should I post it as a new question or edit this question? Technically you answered my problem, so I should leave this alone, but I feel like I'd be posting a duplicated.

Comment: Expand your $y'(x)$. Factor out $.9^x$ from the terms in which it's a factor. Note that $.9^x >0 \forall x$. Actually, no need to expand: after factoring, you should have $$.9^x(\ln(0.9)\cdot 650 \cdot 300 x + 300)$$ This will only equal zero when the factor in the parentheses is equal to zero.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that as well. $0.9^x$ can't equal $0$. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Oops, correction: Actually, no need to expand: after factoring, you should have $$.9^x[\ln(0.9)\cdot(300 x + 650) + 300]$$ This will only equal zero when the factor in the brackets is equal to zero.

Answer (score 0):

You were asked to give an approximation, not an exact answer. If you take the derivative and compare it to zero, you get the rather difficult expression:
$$(300x+650)[\ln(0.9)×0.9^x]+0.9^x×300=0$$
We know $\ln (1+x) \sim x$ for small $x$. So, we get:
$$(300-30x-65)0.9^x=0$$
This will only be zero when $235=30x$, or when $x$ is approximately $7.8$